# SQL Query - Creating an INSTEAD OF DELETE that checks existence of value in 2nd table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I am trying to create a delete trigger that will print a message. The trigger should check if an `order` value exists in the `order_details` table. If the value exists in the 2nd table I want to return the value. I have been tinkering for a few days, but I cannot get it to work.

I am new to SQL Server and query creation.
Here is what I pulled together:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_delete_check
ON  orders
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
IF (SELECT order_id
    FROM   orders
    WHERE  order_details.order_id=orders.order_id
    )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'No Delete: Value exists in Order Details table'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
GO
```

Comment: This kind of thing is done with foreign keys, not triggers.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE order_details
ADD CONSTRAINT order_details_order_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
REFERENCES order (order_id);
```

You *could* cascade the delete to depending rows in `order_details` by adding:

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But the default is:

```
ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

which does what your triggers tries to do: roll back the delete if depending rows in `order_details` exist. Read about the [details in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx).